# Passing multiple functions to a class method

Tags: python, function, events, arguments, ironpython

I have defined TaskTimer Class below and that I would like to execute multiple functions when the event is triggered which may or may not have arguements. I would like to come up with a generic way of doing this. My functions are not being executed and I do not undestand why. Are my arguements in t.start() incorrect?

```
import System  
from System.Timers import (Timer, ElapsedEventArgs)


class TaskTimer(object):

    def __init__ (self):
        self.timer = Timer ()
        self.timer.Enabled = False
        self.handlers =[]

    def On_Timed_Event (self,source, event):

        print 'Event fired', event.SignalTime


        for handler in self.handlers:
            handler(*self.my_args,**self.kwargs)

    def start(self,interval, repeat, *args, **kwargs):

        self.repeat = repeat
        self.run = True                     #True if timer is running
        self.timer.Interval= interval
        self.timer.Enabled = True

        self.my_args= args
        self.kwargs = kwargs


        for x in self.my_args:
            self.handlers.append(x)

        self.timer.Elapsed += self.On_Timed_Event  


def func1(a,b):
    print 'function 1. this function does task1'
    print '1...1...1...'
    return None

def func2(d):
    print 'Function 2. This function does something'
    print '2...2...2...'
    return None 

def func3(a,b,c):
    print 'function 3. This function does something else'
    return None


def main():

    t= TaskTimer()
    D= {'fun2':'func2', 'arg2':'3'}
    t.start(5000,False,func1, func2, func3, a= 1, b=3, c=4, d=D)


if __name__ == '__main__':   
    main()
```

---

I am experimenting so I edited the def_Timed_Event function and func1, func2 and func3 as shown below. I also added print statement to the functions as suggested by @Ewan. Does Python automatically substitute function variables from **self.kwargs?

```
def On_Timed_Event (self,source, event):

    print '\nEvent fired', event.SignalTime

    for handler in self.handlers:
        print 'length of self.handlers', len(self.handlers)
        print 'args', self.my_args
        print 'kwargs', self.kwargs
        print 'handler', handler
        handler(**self.kwargs)
        self.handler[handler](**self.kwargs)

def func1(a,b):
    print 'function 1. this function does task1'
    print 'func1', a,b
    print '1...1...1...'
    return None

def func2(d):
    print 'Function 2. This function does something'
    print 'func2', d
    print '2...2...2...'
    return None 

def func3(a,b,c):
    print 'function 3. This function does something else'
    print 'func3', a,b,c
    return None
```

The code runs inside IronPyhton console. 
![IronPython_console][2]

```
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYW0S.jpg
```

Comment: What are you expecting `self.timer.Elapsed += self.On_Timed_Event` to do?

Comment: @jonrsharpe    It is supposed to execute the code in On_timed_Events. It is partially doing it but I am having trouble executing the functions. I would like to pass any number of functions to TaskTimer. I will edit my question to provide more detail.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I can see you having trouble with this line:

`handler(*self.my_args,**self.kwargs)`

As you aren't accepting any extra `kwargs` in `func1`, `func2` or `func3` I would expect to see the following if it was reaching them:

```
In [1]: def func1(a, b):
   ...:     print(a, b)
   ...:

In [2]: kwg = {'a':1, 'b':3, 'c':4, 'd':{'fun2':'func2', 'arg2':'3'}}

In [3]: func1(**kwg)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-12557b6441ce> in <module>()
----> 1 func1(**kwg)

TypeError: func1() got an unexpected keyword argument 'c'
```

Personally I'd put some decent logging/debug statements in to find out where your program is getting in your stack.

- Is the program completing successfully or are you getting a TraceBack?
- What is this designed to do: `self.timer.Elapsed += self.On_Timed_Event`?

  - It looks like it's supposed to be adding a time onto your `timer.Elapsed` value however nothing is returned by `self.On_Timed_Event`
- `On_Timed_Event` takes 2 parameters (`source, event`) however you don't seem to be passing them in, this should also cause the program to fail.
- Are you seeing `Event fired` in your `stdout` or is the program not getting to `On_Timed_Event` at all? This may show a problem in your `System.Timers` code.

Comment: I followed your advice and added print statements to the functions. However, the arguments do not seemed to be passed into the functions. Is Python supposed to make arguement substition using **self.kwargs? The code runs iside IronPython console. I tried to add an image of the console but it did work.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It appears that I have to modify the arguments list for func1, func2 and func3 to include **kwargs.